# Qual a forma correta de passar os dados de paginação no response REST?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, restful

Em aplicações mais robustas, onde uma tabela pode ter milhões de registros, é importante implementar a paginação em uma API REST. 
Já vi em alguns projetos duas formas de devolver as informações de paginação (número da página, tamanho da página, ordenação, etc)

#### No corpo da resposta

- As informações de paginação ficam no corpo, tais como *totalPages, totalElements, size, number*, etc;
- A lista de elementos é empacotada em um array `content`, sendo parte do objeto página retornado;

#### No header da resposta

- As informações de paginação ficam header, tais como *totalPages, totalElements, size, number,* etc;
- A lista de elementos é o array principal retornado;

Levando em conta o design de uma API REST, qual a forma correta de passar os dados de paginação no response?

Comment: Essa é uma desição de design complexa, não acredito que exista uma resposta "correta"... Dito isso, existe uma tendência de enquadrar paginação no padrão HATEOAS com informações sobre paginação no corpo, além de links para outras páginas (primeira, próxima, anterior, última). Esse padrão é bem prático, principalmente quanto o client possui os respectivos métodos *next*, *previous*, etc implementados para ti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o correto seria passar essas informações no Header do response, pois constituem meta dados da requisição (informação adicional) e portanto deveriam está no Header da resposta. Com isso o payload armazenaria informação que de fato tem valor para aplicação, o que até mesmo facilitaria o entendimento do cliente que vai consumir sua API.

Por exemplo, a requisição `GET /recursos?intervalo=0-25` poderia receber como resposta o cabeçalho:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: 0-25/100 
...
```

Content-Range para indicar o intervalo da lista de recursos retornado e o total de recursos da consulta completa e status '206 Partial Content'  para indicar que esse é só uma parte da listagem (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Range)

Adicionalmente, você pode ser utilizar o head link para prover informações de navegação para sua resposta (https://www.w3.org/wiki/LinkHeader):

```
Link : <https://api/recursos?intervalo=0-25>; rel="primeiro", 
<https://api/recursos?intervalo=0-25>; rel="anterior", 
<https://api/recursos?intervalo=51-76>; rel="proximo", 
<https://api/recursos?intervalo=51-76>; rel="ultimo"
```

Comment: Descobri também que existe uma padronização para isso, chamada Web Linking RFC 5988 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5988).

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde Murillo,
Pelo que tenho estudado e implementado em alguns projetos de APIs REST, fico com a 1ª opção, isso porque as informações totalPages, totalElements, size, number, são dados que compõem a informação, então acredito que faz mais sentido estarem presentes no body.

Aqui onde trabalho temos um fluxo grande de dados trafegados, e utilizamos a 1ª opção, o header utilizamos para lidar com dados de funcionamento das APIs como tokens e outros tipos de dados de configuração e gerenciamento.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o mais interessante é passar no corpo da resposta as informações da páginação.

Vendo o padrão JSON API você pode verificar que eles também fazem isso.

http://jsonapi.org/examples/#pagination